# Reading form action property in IE6, if form has a field named "action"

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6, forms

Given the `form` below:

```
<form id="myForm" action="index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="list" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How can I get the value for the `action` property of the form (*index.php*) using IE6?

Hint: I have tried

```
document.getElementById('myForm').action
```

and

```
document.getElementById('myForm').getAttribute('action')
```

But neither of them work. They both return the `input` field (`document.getElementById('myForm').action.value == 'list'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way, using the node's [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.attributes) collection:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").attributes["action"].value
```

Test page to try it out (also demonstrates the brokenness of getAttribute as mentioned David Dorward's answer):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Form Action Access</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function dotAccess()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("myForm").action.value);
}
function getAttributeAccess()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("myForm").getAttribute("action"));
}
function attributesAccess()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("myForm").attributes["action"].value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="foo">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bar">
  <input type="button" onclick="dotAccess()" value="form.action">
  <input type="button" onclick="getAttributeAccess()" value='form.getAttribute("action")'>
  <input type="button" onclick="attributesAccess()" value='form.attributes["action"]'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now that's how an answer should look like! "Here are your options" and "here's what I've found" Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

David's right. Here's a less nasty way than the regex though:

```
var action= document.forms.myForm.cloneNode(false).action;
```

(Because the clone is shallow, there is no ‘input name="action"’ inside the new form element to confuse it.)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a simple way.

The presence of the action field, clobbers the action property of the form and getAttribute is broken in IE < 8.

The only way I can think of is to get dirty with regular expressions. I would very strongly suggest changing the form to use a different name for the field than 'action' if at all possible instead.

```
var form = document.forms.myForm;
var action = form.getAttribute('action');
if (action === form.elements.action) {
       // getAttribute broken;
       var string = form.outerHTML;
       return string.match(/action=(.*?)[> ]/)[1];
} else {
       return action;
}
```

That regular expression might not be robust enough. So test it hard if you do use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found another way: using or cloning the [`readAttribute`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/readAttribute) method available in prototypejs.