# An input in a form named 'action' overrides the form's action property. Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form marked up as

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="form1.php" style="width:405px">
```

Ordinarily, I could access the action of the form in javascript by referring to the `.action` of the form object, for example

```
document.forms[0].action
```

which would return the value

```
form1.php
```

However, if I have, as a component of the form, an item named "action", this "action" becomes the content of the form's action. That is, if the form markup contains, for example,

```
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="check" />
```

Then

```
document.forms[0].action
```

returns the value

```
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="check" />
```

Now, I did work out how to get around this: by using

```
document.forms[0].getAttribute("action")
```

However, it's a nasty gotcha that confused me for too long. Is this a bug? A known gotcha of DOM management? Or should I just get into the habit of using .getAttribute()?

Comment: Not a bug, the browser is emulating [IE behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1378155/1048572) which started `form[elementname]` style - correct would be `form.elements[elementname]`. However I had expected the attribute to shadow the input…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not call this a bug. This effect occurs, because attributes can be read by using `element.attributename` and named inputs inside a form can be accessed in the same way, `formelement.inputname`. If there is an attribute and an input with the same name, there is no guarantee which one will be used. It probably behaves differently in different browsers.

I personally use `getAttribute` if I am reading a known attribute that was included in the markup or added using `setAttribute` in JavaScript. For dynamic values like, for example, the `checked` attribute of a checkbox, I don't use `getAttribute`. But this is more a question of personal preference, I guess.

Comment: One difference when using `getAttribute` is that, unlike the `action` property, it can return relative urls.

Answer (score 3):

I am fighting this behaviour at the moment too (7 years later!)

It is very hacky, but you are able to access and call the `action` getter directly by using the following.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLFormElement.prototype, 'action').get.call(document.forms[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered this for a number of different form attrs, I finally worked up a general solution based on @threenplusone's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65066146/681277).

The following code creates a `safeForm()` function that wraps any Forms in a Proxy object which transparently "unmasks" any form properties that have been hidden ("id", "name", "action", etc).  All other values are returned as-is.

```js
// get property descriptor from wherever in chain
function getPropertyDescriptor (obj, name) {
    let desc;
    while(obj && !(desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name))) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return desc;
}

// helpers for safeForm()
const isFormProxy = Symbol("isFormProxy"),
    formHandler = {
        get(form, prop) {
            if (prop === isFormProxy) return true;  // helper to detect proxy
            let value = form[prop];
            if (value instanceof HTMLElement && value.name === prop){
                let desc = getPropertyDescriptor(HTMLFormElement.prototype, prop);
                if(desc){
                    return desc.get.call(form);
                }
                // NOTE: comment out next line to include elements                 
                //       that aren't shadowing a form attribute.                 
                return;
            }
            return value;
        },
        set(form, prop, value){
            if(prop === isFormProxy) return;
            form[prop] = value;
        },
    };


// frontend function
function safeForm (elem){
     if(elem instanceof HTMLFormElement && !elem[isFormProxy]){
         return new Proxy(elem, formHandler);
     }
     return elem;
}
```